# Can whatsapp be accessed by websites?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I was wondering if it were possible for websites to send messages through my whatsapp without my permission, even if I mistakely clicked on an advert?

I read about whatsapp's API but it does not say much about this?

Any wisdom on this?

Comment: Close-voters: I don't think this question is Android-independent, because a website might be able to send a message by sending an Intent to the WhatsApp app, like how they can open app pages in the Play Store app.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

There seems to be no possible way for any website to do this without having your WhatsApp "security token".

**What can a website do?**

There is something called WhatsApp URL which lets websites build a custom link that upon pressing will redirect you to WhatsApp so you can share their content to any contact you select manually.

[(See more on WhatsApp FAQ)](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012).